# Why am I getting undefined when extracting values from my array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date-fns, react-calendar

This might be a little long, but I will try to keep it brief. For background. I am building a Calendar app using React, react-calendar and date-fns.

I am trying to extract values from an array of object in a forEach loop.

The array is:

```
datesToAddContentTo = [
    {date: '2023-11-24T22:00:00.000Z', user: 'Hilsie', isValid: true},
    {date: '2023-11-25T22:00:00.000Z', user: 'Hilsie', isValid: true},
    {date: '2023-11-26T22:00:00.000Z', user: 'Hilsie', isValid: true},
    {date: '2023-11-27T22:00:00.000Z', user: 'Hilsie', isValid: true} 
]
```

Below is the code of how the array is being created:

```
const datesToAddContentTo = [
    dateList.map((item) => {
      return {
        date: item.fullDate,
        user: item.user,
        isValid: isValid(
          parse(String(item.fullDate), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX", new Date())
        ),
      };
    }),
  ];

console.log(datesToAddContentTo);
```

After creating the array I am then trying to extract the values of the array so I can use it to validate/compare the dates to the date on a Calendar so I can display info on the calendar tiles. Below the code that I use to do this:

```
const tileContent = useCallback(({ date, view }) => {
    datesToAddContentTo.forEach((obj) => {
      let user = obj.user;
      console.log("This is: " + user);
      let sDate = parse(
        String(obj.date),
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX",
        new Date()
      );
      console.log("sDate is: " + sDate);
      let tDate = date;
      console.log("sDate: " + sDate + ". tDate: " + tDate);
      if (view === "month") {
        if (isSameDay(sDate, tDate)) {
          return <p className={`success ${user}`}>Success</p>;
        } else {
          return <p className="fail">NOT Success</p>;
        }
      }
    });
  }, []);
```

What I was expecting here was for the date to be extracted from the array as I have done on many occasions and to then be able to parse and compare the dates. What I see however is that the values from the array are returned/extracted as undefined.

I believe I need to be digging a little deeper since I have an array of object, but I am not certain if that is indeed what is causing my problem.

Comment: It looks like `datesToAddContentTo` contains a single element which is itself the array returned by `dateList.map()`. Try removing the surrounding brackets (`[]`) from `dateList.map()`. Can you double check this or is it just a typo.

Comment: @phuzi man I have been struggling with this for 2 day... Such a rookie error! thanks! I seem to be getting usable values now!

Answer (score 0):

> The array is:

No it isn't.  You've *assumed* that it is, rather than debugged and observed.  Look at how you're building the array:

```
const datesToAddContentTo = [
  dateList.map((item) => {
    //...
  })
];
```

The result of `.map()` is an array.  So your structure would become:

```
const datesToAddContentTo = [
  [
    //...
  ]
];
```

You have an array which contains an array.  So in the call to `.forEach()`:

```
datesToAddContentTo.forEach((obj) => {
```

The value of `obj` is an array.  And arrays have no properties called `user` or `date`, so those values are `undefined`.

The simplest fix is probably to just remove the enclosing array notation when creating your array:

```
const datesToAddContentTo = dateList.map((item) => {
  //...
});
```